# Inserting JPG image in JSP through css

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have JSP page for which I wish to add a logo in the form of jpg file. I placed the jpg file inside a folder caled images within WebContent folder in eclipse. But The image is not getting loaded when i run the fllowing code.

```
<style type="text/css">
body
{
background: url("/images/bg-logo.jpg")top right no-repeat; 
}
</style>
```

Could anyone tell whats wrong in this code.

Comment: Assuming that your body has a height because of the content, is the path to the image ok? You can check that from the browser with firebug for example

Comment: @StefanI checked my path in firebug and it shows error saying that there is no image found. But the jpg image is in folder images inside the WebContaent directory in workspace

Comment: You can also try to find the image based on the location of your css file; if you have in the root folder for example the folder css (where your css file is included) and on the same level the folder images, then you can try in css the path: ../images/bg-logo.jpg
Be sure you have the images directory next to the jsp file.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
body
{
background: url("images/bg-logo.jpg")top right no-repeat; 
}
</style>
```

Comment: Might I ask how this is different than the code OP posted? Could you explain more of what the problem is and how your code solve it?

Comment: wow a long time since I  posted that, but yeah, his pathing was wrong on the url, he was calling `/images/` which goes straight to the root of the current url whereas he was probably trying to access the images directory within his current page directory.

Another thing he really should be doing is having that in a separate CSS file.